# How to add expendable sidebar in Angular 9

Tags: angular

In have integrated AdminLte 3 theme in angular 9 successfully.

but when is logged in to dashboard and click sidebar expendable link it redirect to login page.

if i click the name it works fine do not need to refresh.but i can not understand why it is happening.

if i refresh dashboard without click expendable link it works fine. i google it several time but not find any solution any body help thanks in advance.

this is sidebar

[image]

this is my sidebar html

```
<nav class="mt-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
        <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                <p>
                    Order Details item
                    <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a [routerLink]="[ '/order-list' ]" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                        <p>Order List</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                <p>
                    Details item
                    <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview" style="display: none;">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a [routerLink]="[ '/city-list' ]" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                        <p>City List</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a [routerLink]="[ '/item-list' ]" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                        <p>Item List</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Comment: @Vikas OP is using Bootstrap, not sure it's necessary to add Material just to get an expandable sidebar

Comment: i do not need Material sidebar just bootstarp

Comment: anyone have any idea how can i fix this?